# Simple NHibernate Eager Loading confusion

Tags: nhibernate

I have a very simple master-child model:

**WorkflowEscalationPolicy<--WorkflowEscalation**.

The WorkflowEscalations are accessible from the `WorkflowEscalationPolicy.Escalations` property.

I want to eagerly fetch the escalations when I get the `WorkflowEscalationPolicy` items.

I have a method that gets all escalation policies. I have tried using this:

```
IEnumerable<IWorkflowEscalationPolicy> results = 
  Session
 .Query<WorkflowEscalationPolicy>()
 .Fetch(x=>x.Escalations)
 .Where(q=>q.ApplicationKey==applicationKey);
```

and this:

```
IEnumerable<IWorkflowEscalationPolicy> results = 
 Session
 .CreateCriteria<WorkflowEscalationPolicy>()
 .SetFetchMode("Escalations", FetchMode.Eager)
 .List<WorkflowEscalationPolicy>();
```

to accomplish this, but neither work - in that the child Escalations collection remains empty. I know that there are `WorkflowEscalations` in the database.

My mapping files:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="FB.SimpleWorkflow.NHibernate"
                   namespace="FB.SimpleWorkflow.NHibernate.Model" >
    <class name="WorkflowEscalationPolicy" table="SW_WorkflowEscalationPolicy" >
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="ApplicationKey" />
        <property name="ActivityKey" />
        <property name="InstanceKey" />     
        <property name="State" />
        <property name="EscalateAfterSeconds" />
        <property name="MaximumEscalationsPerTransition" />

        <set name="Escalations" table="SW_WorkflowEscalation" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
            <key column="WorkflowEscalationPolicyId" />
            <one-to-many class="WorkflowEscalation" />
        </set>
    </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="FB.SimpleWorkflow.NHibernate"
                   namespace="FB.SimpleWorkflow.NHibernate.Model" >
    <class name="WorkflowEscalation" table="SW_WorkflowEscalation" >
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="EscalatedTimeStamp" />
        <property name="EscalatedByUserName" />
        <property name="EscalatedOnHost" />

        <many-to-one name="WorkflowEscalationPolicy" column="WorkflowEscalationPolicyID" />
        <many-to-one name="WorkflowActivityInstanceTransition" column="WorkflowActivityInstanceTransitionId" />
    </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

What is the difference between the two and what am I missing here? I thought that in the first instance NHibernate refers to the mapping files for loading strategies?

NHibernate is v3.1

### **Update: 6 June 2013**

Further investigations thanks to @cremor ...

I've profiled the generated SQL that the query executes and I get:

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id4_1_, 
    this_.ApplicationKey as Applicat2_4_1_, 
    this_.ActivityKey as Activity3_4_1_, 
    this_.InstanceKey as Instance4_4_1_, 
    this_.State as State4_1_, 
    this_.EscalateAfterSeconds as Escalate6_4_1_, 
    this_.MaximumEscalationsPerTransition as MaximumE7_4_1_, 
    escalation2_.WorkflowEscalationPolicyID as Workflow5_3_, 
    escalation2_.Id as Id3_, 
    escalation2_.Id as Id2_0_, 
    escalation2_.EscalatedTimeStamp as Escalate2_2_0_, 
    escalation2_.EscalatedByUserName as Escalate3_2_0_, 
    escalation2_.EscalatedOnHost as Escalate4_2_0_, 
    escalation2_.WorkflowEscalationPolicyID as Workflow5_2_0_, 
    escalation2_.WorkflowActivityInstanceTransitionID as Workflow6_2_0_ 
    FROM SW_WorkflowEscalationPolicy this_ 
    left outer join SW_WorkflowEscalation escalation2_ on this_.Id=escalation2_.WorkflowEscalationPolicyID
```

Which is what I would expect.

This generates the correct SQL, with the single detail Escalation record to the right of the master EscalationPolicy record. Therefore, the database is fine, the T-SQL is fine and therefore there is a misunderstanding within the NHibernate somewhere.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Eager loading only means that the Escalations list is loaded directly after the the WorkflowEscalationPolicy object and does not mean that some join is executed.

Comment: Sorry, have added clarification. The Escalations property (of WorkflowEscalation) is empty even though there are records in the database. Maybe that's what I'm not clear on? However, I have seen this code work before! Something has changed and I accept I've broken it but need to figure out how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Escalations` collection is empty when it shouldn't you don't have a problem with eager loading. Because if you don't eager load a collection, NHibernate just loads it when you access it the first time, so you'll never see it as empty. The only difference is that eager loading joins the collection in the same SQL query and lazy loading executes one (or many, known as select n+1 problem) seperate queries.

I don't know if it makes a difference in the database you use, but your key colums are different in the mapping although they should be same (one ends with an upper case "D", one with lower case).

Are you sure that the returned `WorkflowEscalationPolicy` objects are not already in any NHibernate cache? If they are, NHibernate might discard the results of the SQL query and just return the existing objects. Try to create a new session for your query.

PS: Not related to your question, but be careful when eager loading a collection when querying many parent objects. Example: If you have 100 parents and each parent has 100 elements in the collection, your SQL query will return 10000 rows. You won't get 10000 objects from NHinbernate, but all that rows still have to be send from the DB to your client. Better use lazy loading in such a case and map the collection with subselect fetching or batching to prevent a select n+1 problem.

Comment: Thanks @cremor. You've helped me understand that eager loading isn't necessarily equal to eager population, which is what I'm after. Thanks also for your PS, I appreciate this. As a matter of interest this is just a unit test at the moment out of which an API will grow and this will contribute to that - though I am happy about record levels at the moment. <P> Interesting point about case sensitivity, I wasn't aware of this and hadn't seen any mention of it. I've corrected this <P> However it still fails to populate the child collection. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Program.X Are you sure that the returned `WorkflowEscalationPolicy` objects are not already in any NHibernate cache? If they are, NHibernate might discard the results of the SQL query and just return the existing objects. Try to create a new session for your query.

Comment: That's got it. One of no doubt many hidden aspects of NHibernate I need to get acquainted with. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Program.X Good to know. I've added that to the answer so other users having the same problem don't have to read the comments.